# Gluon save properties file

Tags: java, android, gluon-mobile

I have the following bit of code in Android. It is supposed to create a properties file and set up some properties on app init.

```java
String androidFilePath = settingsFolderPath + File.separator + "my.properties";
File ROOT_DIR = Services.get(StorageService.class)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Local storage not supported on this device!"))
        .getPublicStorage("")
        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No local storage found on this device!"));

File settingsFile = new File(ROOT_DIR, androidFilePath);

new File(settingsFile.getParent()).mkdirs();

settingsFile.createNewFile();

Properties properties = new Properties();

String public_lobby = (String) properties.getOrDefault("public_lobby",
        InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
properties.put("public_lobby", public_lobby);

String public_lobby_port = (String) properties.getOrDefault("public_lobby_port", String.valueOf(1257));
properties.put("public_lobby_port", public_lobby_port);

OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(settingsFile.getAbsoluteFile());
        properties.store(output, null);
```

The problem is that when I start the app the properties file is created but never written.

I checked the my manifest and permissions and it seems to me that it is set correctly.

I do not know what to do, please help me.

Comment: You should try closing that OutputStream object to see if that resolves it. Wrap it in a try-with-resources.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions thrown like IOException: Permission denied?

Comment: Have you tried using the `SettingsService`? https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/SettingsService.html